# How to add a site mailbox to an already existing Team Site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-mailboxes

How I can add a site mailbox to an already existing Team Site? When trying to activate the Site Mailbox feature, an error is is shown:

> New Site Mailboxes can no longer be created in SharePoint Online. Consider using Office 365 Groups to connect a team site with an email conversation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

> **Removal of Site Mailboxes in SharePoint Online**
>
> **Status**: Archive
>
> **Action Required by**: March 1, 2017
>
> **Details**: Beginning March 2017, new SharePoint Online organizations
>   will no longer have access to the Site Mailbox feature, existing
>   SharePoint Online organizations will no longer be able to create new
>   Site Mailboxes; however, any Site Mailboxes provisioned prior to March
>   2017 will continue to function. In September 2017, we will have a
>   process in place allowing you to transition your existing Site Mailbox
>   site to an Office 365 Group. We will communicate again in June 2017,
>   via Message Center, with more details. If you are using the Site
>   Mailbox feature in SharePoint Online, you should consider
>   transitioning to Office 365 Groups, to support email-centric
>   collaborative scenarios.

This is quote from **[Office 365 Planned Service Changes for 2017 – Admin Action Required](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/skywriter/2017/01/19/office-365-planned-service-changes-2017/)**. So as stated, the Site Mailbox feature can no longer be activated with SharePoint Online.

The alternative as provided by Microsoft would be to move to **Office 365 Groups**. O365 Groups support email-centric collaborative scenarios, which should fulfill e.g. SharePoint's Site Mailbox functionality. [Learn about Office 365 groups](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-about-Office-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

---

You can active Site Mailbox by going to **Site settings** > **Site Features** > Activate **Site Mailbox**.

[image]

Comment: Hello, but there saying new site mailboxes can no longer be created in SharePoint Online.Considered using Office 365 Groups to connect a team site with an email conversation. What I need to do in this case?

Comment: @J.U that seems to be the case currently. I've updated the answer. In a nutshell, this means that SP's Site Mailbox feature can no longer be activated. Instead, for the same functionality, you should have a look at Office 365 Groups.

Comment: I investigated, it seems the Office 365 Group working for Modern Team Sites. But if the team site is not like Modern Team Site, how I can use Office 365 Group instead?

Comment: @J.U that seems to be the case. I'm afraid there's no workaround for that.